# Cómo imprimir en un jtextarea de un japplet desde una clase

Tags: java, java-swing

Hola verán tengo este ejercicio de programación de java, apenas voy empezando, la cosa es que tengo ingresar 3 numeros que el usuario quiera, despues tengo que poner 2 checkbox de manera que el usuario elija si quiere ordenarlos de manera ascendente o descendente, al dar en el boton calcular, se debe mostrar los numeros ordenados en el jtextarea de la manera que el usuario elijió.

A nivel de programación, ya terminé todo practicamente, y sé que el algoritmo de ordenamiento de datos funciona bien y todo porque ya lo había hecho pero SIN USAR CLASES SOLO PROGRAMADO NORMAL, pero tengo un problema... en el ejercicio dice que debo crear 2 clases una que se llame Ascendente y otra que se llame Descendente, todo perfecto hasta ahí, luego esas clases deben instanciarse con los numeros que ingrese el usuario y dentro de ambas clases debe haber un metodo que se llame calcularorden() el cual debe ordenar los datos (dependiendo el nombre de la clase) y mostrarlo en el jtextarea de mi japplet, pero la cosa es que cuando puse las clases simplemente es como que el programa no reconociera. Les dejo mi codigo para que lo checken ahí dejé la docuimentacion explicando las líneas.

Este es el evento al dar click en el boton calcular:

```
private void jbtncalcularActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    int n1, n2, n3;
    //capturo valores
    n1 = Integer.parseInt(jtxtn1.getText());
    n2 = Integer.parseInt(jtxtn2.getText());
    n3 = Integer.parseInt(jtxtn3.getText());
    //borro textarea para que no se vayan acumulando numeros
    jtxtar.setText(null);
    //si el checkbox ascendente está marcado hace lo de este if
    if(jcheckas.isSelected())
    {
        //envio como parametro mis 3 valores, instanciando mi clase
        Ascendente a = new Ascendente(n1,n2,n3);
        //llamo a mi metodo calcularoden dentro de la clase Ascendente para que imprima en el jtextarea
        a.CalcularOrden();
    }
    else if(jcheckdes.isSelected())
    {
        //instancio mi clase descendente
        Descendente d = new Descendente(n1, n2, n3);
        //llamo a mi metodo dentro de mi clase para que imprima en el jtextarea
        d.CalcularOrden();
    }
}
```

Esta es mi clase Descendente:

```
package ejercicio8principal;
//hago que mi clase herede los objetos del japplet ordenar para obtener el jtextarea
public class Descendente extends Ordenar{
    private int n1, n2, n3;
//capturo mis 3 valores en los campos de la clase mediante el constructor
public Descendente(int n1, int n2, int n3)
{
    this.n1 = n1;
    this.n2 = n2;
    this.n3 = n3;
}

public void CalcularOrden()
{
    int arreglo[] = new int[3];
    int aux;
     //meto mis 3 valores dentro de un arreglo para que me sea más facil la manipulación del orden de datos
    arreglo[0] = n1;
    arreglo[1] = n2;
    arreglo[2] = n3;


    //hago los movimientos de valores con estos for
    for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
        {
            for(int i=0; i<3-1; i++)
            {
                if(arreglo[i]<arreglo[i+1])
                {
                    aux = arreglo[i];
                    arreglo[i] = arreglo[i+1];
                    arreglo[i+1] = aux;
                }
            }
        }
    //una vez ordenado los datos imprimo los datos en mi jtextarea
        for(int i =0; i<3; i++)
        {
            jtxtar.append(String.valueOf(arreglo[i]+", "));
        }

}
```

}

Y practicamente mi clase Ascendente es igual a mi clase Descendente, solo cambia en la lógica de ordenar los for, pero no tiene gran relevancia puesto que sé que funciona bien.

Practicamente ya lo había hecho, pero sin usar clases solamente programando donde está el evento del boton calcular usando los for y listo. Por favor les agradecería su ayuda por si estoy haciendo algo mal, solo necesito que el metodo calcularorden() de las clases imprima en el jtextarea de mi japplet. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

En la clase `Descendente` y `Ascendente` puedes colocar un atríbuto de tipo arreglo

```
private int[] arregloOrdenado = new int[3];
```

Modifica el método `calcularOrden()` para que los valores los guarde en el arregloOrdenado

```
arregloOrdenado[0] = n1;
arregloOrdenado[1] = n2;
arregloOrdenado[2] = n3;
```

crear un método que retorne el arreglo ordenado

```
public int[] getArregloOrdenado(){
  return arregloOrdenado;
}
```

modifica el metodo del evento click

```
if(jcheckas.isSelected()){
  //envio como parametro mis 3 valores, instanciando mi clase
  Ascendente a = new Ascendente(n1,n2,n3);
  //llamo a mi metodo calcularoden dentro de la clase Ascendente para que imprima en el jtextarea
  a.CalcularOrden();
  jtxtar.setText(Arrays.toString(a.getArregloOrdenado()));
}
```

Comment: Mil Gracias!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! fué la solución a todo! Gracias!!!!!!!!!